# android - refresh all the thumbnails on the device before loading the gallery?

Tags: android, thumbnails, mediastore

I have an app which uses cursors to load thumbnails (into a gridview) from the mediastore:

```
        CursorLoader cursorLoader = null;
    if (Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        String[] from = { MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.TITLE };
        projection = from;
        String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
                + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE + " OR "
                + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
                + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
        Uri queryUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
        cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, queryUri, projection,
                selection, null, MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED
                        + " DESC");
    } else {
        String[] from = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED };
        projection = from;
        Uri sourceImageUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, sourceImageUri, null, null,
                null, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC");
    }
    Cursor cursor = null;
    if (cursorLoader != null) {
        cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
        mGalleryAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, projection,
                to, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
        gallery.setAdapter(mGalleryAdapter);
        gallery.setOnItemClickListener(myOnItemClickListener);
    }
```

However, some newer images are loaded without thumbnails, which is rather silly. The thumbnails are only generated when I open the gallery app (Photos) on my phone.

How can I refresh all the thumbnails programatically on the device so there are no images left blank without a thumbnail?

I would like this to work on all Android version, including 4.4. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit:

Use `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail()` or `MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail()` - it's a blocking class and generates a new bitmap if it doesn't find one. Much simpler.

You simply need the MediaStore ID of the file, which I assume you have, and you can use the standard getContentResolver() in your Activity or through a context. This method also allows for you to get a Bitmap directly in MINI or MICRO sizes.

More on this [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.html#getThumbnail%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20long,%20long,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29).

---

### Old answer:

As indivisible says, you can use

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                    Uri.parse("file://"
                    + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

However, that will not work on Android 4.4 (I think), so consider using the MediaScanner class for API 19+.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to trigger a rescan with this:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                        Uri.parse("file://"
                        + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

You may need to alter the path to suit your needs.

[Found here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/waOFIm899II)

---

And if you wanted to wait for the scan to complete before moving forward you will need to register a receiver for the `ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED` intent.

[Details and discussion on that here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers)/RdvA7y4MqfE

---

kaiwid23 suggests this doesn't work for 4.4+. In that case you can manually control the scanner with a [`MediaScannerConnection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html).

You will want to use the [`MediaConnection.scanFile()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener%29) method. I don't know if it works recursively if supplied a directory or whether it just accepts single paths though.

In this case you pass an `OnScanCompletedListener` in the constructor so monitoring for the scan to complete is actually much easier.